# How to add a separator between context menus using shell extension dll C++

Tags: winapi, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I have created a context menu using Shell Extension DLL (C++). When user clicks on any explorer folder, the newly created context menu will be displayed which has  sub menus. I want to add a line separator between the sub menus

Answer (score 7):

Using

```
InsertMenu(hMenu, indexMenu++, MF_SEPARATOR|MF_BYPOSITION, 0, NULL);
```

works fine for me. With `hMenu` being the menu handle, and `indexMenu` as the menu item index to insert.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the item in response to `QueryContextMenu` use `InsertMenuItem` with the `MFT_SEPARATOR` flag.